# MySQL 8.0.16 (Windows) Group Replication Fresh Setup : Not able to add second member

Tags: mysql, high-availability, mysql-8.0, mysql-cluster, mysql-group-replication

I am trying to setup MySQL HA using Group Replication feature. Referred instruction from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication.html. Read & tried all steps multiple times to ensure all steps are followed properly, but same message all the time. 
I will add 3rd and 4th node as well once the issue is resolved. Once this setup is POCed at Windows, I will repeat on Linux followed by Production (Linux)

Error logs while adding second member in group

A)

```
mysql> START GROUP_REPLICATION;
ERROR 3092 (HY000): The server is not configured properly to be an active member of the group. Please see more details on error log.
```

B)
Server Log of second MySQL DB server

```
2020-01-05T10:45:13.734994Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011526] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'This member has more executed transactions than those present in the group. Local transactions: 1aaf20e2-2fa5-11ea-a9f1-040e3c9a1821:1 > Group transactions: aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa:1,
f28d474c-2fa1-11ea-8748-040e3c9a1821:1'
2020-01-05T10:45:13.744824Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011522] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'The member contains transactions not present in the group. The member will now exit the group.'
```

C) 
Server Log of first MySQL DB server

```
2020-01-05T10:13:07.033377Z 11 [System] [MY-010597] [Repl] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_applier' executed'. Previous state master_host='', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2020-01-05T10:45:15.735673Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011499] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Members removed from the group: L-156179931:3326'
```

Answer (score 0):

The second member has transactions that aren't present on the master and isn't able to join to the group.

You should try to understand what is causing the transaction, checking GTID_EXECUTED (`SELECT @@global.gtid_executed;`) after each command and see the culprit.

Comment: Then what? how do you solve it?

Comment: You need to remove all transactions that you have on joiner server and START GROUP REPLICATION.

You can read official docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-getting-started.html

Or you can use InnoDB: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-introduction.html that use group replication and helps configure everything.